# Crystal Report Syntax color font change not working

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-server

Can someone help me out why this crystal syntax isn't working on this font change? I Can't figure it out.
The data is grouped.

```
IF {command.section}=3 then crRed else
IF {command.section}=4 and {command.AYB}=1 then CRBlue else
IF {command.section}=4 and {Command.Value}>{Strikezone} then crRed else
IF {command.section}=4 and {Command.Value}<{Strikezone} then crgreen else
CRBlack
```

Basically the data is in a group. I want section 4 the logic is the issue.
If I run it as is anything that has {command.AYB}=1 it changes to blue but it doesn't process the next two lines for red or green.
If I comment out the CRBLUE line it processes the red or green.

WHy isn't it working and how do I get it to work for section 4 where if this other value is 1 it will be blue and if not then if it is greater then or less then the strikezone it will be red or green?? I can't get all 3 to work for the
{command.section}=3 logic in the syntax.

Comment: in your group where you are using this formula command.ayb is always 1 and hence it is not allowing to move to next `else if...check the value of AYB in that group and change accordingly

Comment: No - the no 1 value are going all black. It's changing the color properly if it's 1 or not but not doing the red or green.......however if I comment out the line with AYB=1 the red and green works

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own issue but should have give more info. 
I added:

```
IF {command.section}=3 then crRed else
IF {command.section}=4 and {Command.Value}>{Strikezone} and {command.AYB}<>1 then crRed else
IF {command.section}=4 and {Command.Value}<{Strikezone} and {command.AYB}<>1 then crGreen else
IF {command.section}=4 and {command.AYB}=1 then crBlue else
crBlack
```

I added in so it doesn't equal 1 and Also the missing values were NULL so I added in the command so that missing values weren't null they were 0. Field was hidden. Couldve done it another way but I don't think it liked the NULLs very well when looking at those fields.